# Activating a JButton via keyboard

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a `JDialog` with two buttons: an OK button and a Cancel button.
I would like the Cancel button to be activated by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and an OK to be activated by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>. Can someone give me some suggestions for implementing this feature? Thanks!

Comment: Had you considered using a `JOptionPane`?  They work like that 'out of the box'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb "activate" is ambiguous. But regardless, I suggest you read [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: +1 yes, correct way (please update your answer with JButton#doClick())

Comment: +1 for key bindings. It should be noted that you would generally apply these bindings to the root pane. So you would have code like dialog.getRootPane(), to access the InputMap and ActionMap.